# How can I make sure that my outflow is the same as my inflow?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, design, pressure, pumps

I have a basin that is 110 mm wide, 200 mm long, and 15 mm deep. The walls are 2 mm thick. It has water being pumped into it at a rate of 0.1078 gpm from one side. In order to ensure that this pan does not overflow, how many 1.5 mm holes do I need to put at the bottom of this pan (Q outflow = Q inflow)? I’d ideally like to have the water drip out rather than stream. It’s also possible to change the diameter of the holes because I’ll be 3D printing it. I’m new to fluid dynamics and I need some direction!

Comment: The best way is to do a test

Comment: yeah, no way you will get this right via equations.

Comment: To give you some direction on how you might test this: make a 3d printed version of your basin with a lot of 1.5mm holes in it. Then, fill up most of the holes and put water in the basin. Start unplugging holes until the flow is as you desire.

Comment: Seal your basin.  Inflow and outflow will both be 0.  Need some inflow? Seal everything except outflow hole(s) and the inflow hole and fill completely.  Also if the only concern is overflow, why not just use a tall hole.  When level exceeds it, outflow will eventually equal inflow.  You can reroute to the bottom...

Comment: @Chris_abc might just have to do this since I’m struggling to figure it out with just equations… Only problem is I don’t own a personal 3d printer, so I have to outsource the printing and want to get it right in one go.

Comment: You can experiment with cans and bottles.  Be sure to note the depth of water above the hole since this determines pressure.

Comment: @Skuz you're never going to get this exactly right anyway, let alone getting this right based on equations. Flow dynamic equations are really nothing more than a rough approximation based on numerous assumptions. What is this project anyway? Why do you have such a specific inflow, and why do you have such specific dimensions?

Comment: @Chris_abc I figured haha! I’m going to go with your suggestion and print as many holes as i can and just plug them as I see fit with hot glue (or something). It’s just a personal project I decided to make - a diorama with artificial “rain.” I found the inflow from the pump I bought, and experimented with its strength traveling up the height of the diorama. The dimensions I essentially chose myself, and can freely alter.